# "Error in as.Formula(formula) : could not find function "as.Formula"" in my codee

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, stochastic

While using sfa analysis package this error is coming,"Error in as.Formula(formula) : could not find function "as.Formula"

My code:

```
install.packages("sfa") 
library(frontier)
library(sfa)
truncated_normal<-sfa(formula = lMILK ~ lLAND + lFEED + lCOWS + lLABOR, data = cs)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What does the `traceback()` look like? I don't see `as.Formula` in the source code of the package.

Comment: `as.Formula` appears to be from the package `Formula`. Have you tried loading that package manually?